# How to customize the barchart labels using mpandroidchart?

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

(https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Samuel_Ajibade2/publication/312043976/figure/fig4/AS:446694530785282@1483511683083/Displaying-a-simple-Bar-chart-21.png)

check above link for image.

I want to create a barchart like above. I want to customize the x-axis labels and labels above of bar like above image using mpchart in android.
I have tried doing this.

```
 xAxis.setValueFormatter(new IAxisValueFormatter() {
        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, AxisBase axis) {

            int index = (int) value;
            if(index>=0 && index<=xAxisLabel.size()) return xAxisLabel.get(index-1);
            else return "empty";
        }
    });
```

But if label's textsize is more than width of the bar it overlaps to other labels.

```
    barDataSet.setValueFormatter(new IValueFormatter() {

        @Override
        public String getFormattedValue(float value, Entry entry, int dataSetIndex, ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler) {
            //rather than diaplaying value show label
            return entry.getData().toString();
        }
    });
```

This works but it only sets simple text above the bars but I need a little customization like above image (e.g. also images above bars and multiline).

How to do this?